# CAGradientLayer not removing self from view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cagradientlayer

I create a `CAGradientLayer` and add it to a `UIView`:

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [UIColor lightBlueSpreadGradient];
layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
layer.cornerRadius = self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius;
self.gradientLayer = layer;

[self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

I keep a reference to it so I can remove it later:

```
[self.gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

But it doesn't actually remove itself.  I know its being called, everything else in the deselect method is working as intended:

```
-(void)setIsActive:(BOOL)isActive {
    _isActive = isActive;

    if (_isActive) {
        CAGradientLayer *layer = [UIColor lightBlueSpreadGradient];
        layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        layer.cornerRadius = self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius;
        self.gradientLayer = layer;
        DLog(@"inserting self.gradientLayer: %@", self.gradientLayer);

        [self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        DLog(@"is active is false");
        DLog(@"removing overlay");

        DLog(@"self.gradientLayer: %@", self.gradientLayer);
        [self.gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    }
}
```

Log:

```
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | inserting self.gradientLayer: <CAGradientLayer: 0x7e26cce0>
DEBUG | -[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:] | is active is false
DEBUG | -[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:] | removing overlay
DEBUG | -[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:] | removing self.gradientLayer: <CAGradientLayer: 0x7e26cce0>
```

Tap Gesture:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapDectected)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Single Tap Detected method:

```
-(void)singleTapDectected {
    DLog(@"tap detected");

    if (self.isActive) {
        self.isActive = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.isActive = YES;
    }

}
```

Log:

```
DEBUG | -[DatasetTrayCell singleTapDectected] | tap detected
```

Any idea why it won't remove?

EDIT:

Ok, I found the issue, but I don't understand why it was an issue.  So my full method for setting `isActive`:

```
-(void)setIsActive:(BOOL)isActive {
    DLog(@"setting isActive");

    _isActive = isActive;

    if (_isActive) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datasetTrayCell:displayWithCompletionBlock:)]) {
            [self.delegate datasetTrayCell:self displayWithCompletionBlock:^{
                CAGradientLayer *layer = [UIColor lightBlueSpreadGradient];
                layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
                layer.cornerRadius = self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius;
                self.gradientLayer = layer;
                DLog(@"inserting self.gradientLayer: %@", self.gradientLayer);

                [self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
                DLog(@"self.gradientLayer.superlayer: %@", self.gradientLayer.superlayer);
                DLog(@"self.contentView.layer.sublayers: %@", self.contentView.layer.sublayers);

            }];
        }
    }
    else {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datasetTrayCell:removeWithCompletionBlock:)]) {
            [self.delegate datasetTrayCell:self removeWithCompletionBlock:^{
                DLog(@"self.contentView.layer.sublayers: %@", self.contentView.layer.sublayers);
                [self.gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
                DLog(@"self.gradientLayer.superlayer: %@", self.gradientLayer.superlayer);
                DLog(@"removing self.gradientLayer: %@", self.gradientLayer);
            }];
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"delegate does not respond to removeOverlayWithCompletionBlock");
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that the `CAGradientLayer` was created in the block causes it to be created twice:

```
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | inserting self.gradientLayer: <CAGradientLayer: 0x787bdc80>
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | self.gradientLayer.superlayer: <CALayer: 0x7db473f0>
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | self.contentView.layer.sublayers: (
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x787bdc80>",
    "<CALayer: 0x787bd750>"
)
```

and again:

```
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | inserting self.gradientLayer: <CAGradientLayer: 0x78631ce0>
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | self.gradientLayer.superlayer: <CALayer: 0x7db473f0>
DEBUG | __31-[DatasetTrayCell setIsActive:]_block_invoke | self.contentView.layer.sublayers: (
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x78631ce0>",
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x787bdc80>",
    "<CALayer: 0x787bd750>"
)
```

Once I remove that chuck of code out of the block, it performs as it should (it only creates 1 gradient):

```
-(void)setIsActive:(BOOL)isActive {
    DLog(@"setting isActive");

    _isActive = isActive;

    if (_isActive) {
        CAGradientLayer *layer = [UIColor lightBlueSpreadGradient];
        layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        layer.cornerRadius = self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius;
        self.gradientLayer = layer;

        [self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datasetTrayCell:displayWithCompletionBlock:)]) {
            [self.delegate datasetTrayCell:self displayWithCompletionBlock:^{
            }];
        }
    }
    else {
        [self.gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datasetTrayCell:removeWithCompletionBlock:)]) {
            [self.delegate datasetTrayCell:self removeWithCompletionBlock:^{
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Why this happens, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Could you show the logging output please? It's not that I don't believe you or anything, but...

Comment: Oh, also: is this by any chance happening in a cell of a table view? If so, are you remembering to take into account the fact that cells are reused?

Comment: Will add log, and no, this is a custom subclassed `UIView` "cell" I created to be placed in a `UIScrollView`

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I assure you that `removeFromSuperlayer` does remove the layer. Have you tried putting breakpoints in that routine? Maybe things are not going the way you expect. Maybe you accidentally added the gradient multiple times, so now the gradient is being removed but there was another leftover gradient behind it. Whatever the problem is, it doesn't appear to be in the code you're showing here...

Comment: Bingo, I think you are on to something here.  I look at self.contentView.layer.sublayers and there is still a gradient there that shouldn't be.  Looks like 2 gradients are being added.  Looks like that method is being called twice, thus adding 2 gradients and keeping 1 referenced.  Thank you to helping me find the issue.

Comment: And see my answer below, which explains your logging as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the gradient is losing its reference to where it was inserted to. But I haven't a clue how or why.

It isn't "losing its reference". You have, it seems, a strong reference to `self.gradientLayer`. And you have already removed `self.gradientLayer` from its superlayer. But you retained it in your strong reference. Now you are asking for its superlayer, and naturally enough, it has none; you removed it. The gradient layer you are *seeing in the interface* is thus *not* the same as the gradient layer you are talking to. There are (at least) *two* gradient layers in this story. Things have gotten out of sync, and that's confusing you. But the layer is not misbehaving, I assure you.

Comment: Ok, losing the reference was the wrong term.  I followed your suggest, and there are extra gradients that are not being removed. I'll update.

Comment: Yes, you were correct.  I removed the layer and then checked for its supper layer which is pretty silly thing to do.  I should have check for its supper layer before removing it.  With your suggestion to see if there were extra gradients that were not being removed help me track down what the issue was.  I don't understand why it was an issue, but I do have a fix.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I have a bad habit of up voting and thinking that is accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead make so:

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.contentView.layer.sublayers) {
    if([layer isKindOfClass:[GradientLayer class]])
    {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];

    }
}
```